# Trouble migrating Joomla from Linux to Windows server

Tags: php, joomla, windows-server-2008

I'm having some trouble migrating a Joomla website from a Linux server to a Windows server. The database came over fine, Besides that, all I've done is download all the files from the current site, and change configuration.php so the log and tmp directories show "./tmp/" and "./logs/"

I keep having an error in the PHP log stating

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JTable' not
>   found

I've downloaded the site multiple times now, and I'm convinced this is a configuration problem, and not a missing file problem. I've even tried installing a mod for backup on the linux box to try and migrate the site, but sadly the mod had problems installing.

The new server is running IIS 7.5 on Windows Web Server. PHP 5.2.14 and MySQL

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to fix this issue by copying over the existing site, so I ended up using the Microsoft Web Platform to install a new instance of Joomla. Then I copied over all the components, languages, plugins, templates, etc and then restored the database. Bit of a work around but everything is working now.